# Solving $3\times 3$ matrix equations:

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am familiar with finding the inverse of matrices, but struggle to formulate matrix equations.

In this particular question, one is asked to find the elementary matrix E where $E*A = B$. $A$ is given as matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & -1\\1 & 1 & 1\\ -1 & -2 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and $B$ is given as matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & -1\\-1 & -2 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I have been able to find $A^{-1}$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac 23 & \frac 23 & 1\\\frac{-1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & -1\\\frac{-1}{3}& \frac 23 &0\end{bmatrix}$$
However I am unsure on how to use this to find matrix $E$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you certain that the top-right elements of $A$ and $B$ are different? Because I suspect they are supposed to be the same.

Comment: You are correct, they should be the same. The post has been corrected to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't compute $A^{-1}$: Form the $3 \times 6$ "block" matrix $\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}A & I_{3}\end{array}\right]$ and perform a single elementary row operation to convert the left-hand block from $A$ to $B$. The "new" right-hand block is the elementary matrix $E$ you seek.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Performing an elementary row operation is tantamount to multiplying on the left by an elementary matrix $E$. The result of doing a single operation on the block matrix is$$E\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}A & I_{3}\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}EA & E\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}B & E\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$I_3=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$

By definition, $I$ is the identity matrix such that $I_nM=MI_n=M$ for all $n\times n$ matrices $M$.

So you know $EA=B$, if we multiply $A^{-1}$ to the right of both sides:

$$EAA^{-1}=BA^{-1}$$

$$EI=E=BA^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me. Just as an aside, would you be able to explain / point me to any resources which explain how to decide which side of $B$ to place $A^-1$ on? For example, how should one tell whether $E = BA^-1$ or $E = B^-1 * A$?

Comment: @Macro The inverse of $A$, denoted by $A^{-1}$ is multiplied to the right of $B$, so $E=B\times (A^{-1})$ is the answer. (Which means $B$ multiplies with $A^{-1}$ (matrix multiplication)) The other way round is incorrect. You can tell by the way we solve it: we want to eliminate the $A$ in the left hand side in order to find $E$, so we must undo the process of multiplying $A$ (namely multiply it with $A^{-1}$)

Comment: I think I understand now, many thanks.